# deleting common subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

I need a bash script that goes trough a text file, finds lines starting in "Common subdirectories: ", and `rmdir -rf` the two subdirectories. Example of line:

> Common subdirectories: /dir1/dirA and /dir1/dirB

I'm quite new to bash scripting so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep 'Common subdirectories: ' < in.txt |\
  cut -d: -f2 | cut -d" " -f2,4 |\
while read a b
do
  rm -rf "$a" "$b"
done
```

Edit; added quoting, use the same rm command for both

Comment: The beauty of Un*x pipes is that you can build them step by step.

Answer (score 1):

A more succinct version:

```
awk '/^Common subdirectories:/{ system("rm -rf "$3" "$5) }' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete example:

```
for F in `grep 'Common subdirectories' input.txt | cut -d: -f2 | awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "}{ print }' | tr -d ' '`
do
    [ -d "$F" ] && rm -rf $F
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter command:

```
awk '/Common subdirectories:/ { print $3 " " $5 }' in.txt | xargs -n1 rm -rf
```